# Can't call public sub from button click

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to execute a sub procedure contained in a module called calculations, upon the click of a button. In my sheet where the button is placed I have the following code ...

```
Private Sub Button_Calculate_Click()
    'Start main calculation procedure

    MsgBox "Clicked"
    Call Calculate

End Sub
```

In Modules/Calculations, I have the following code ...

```
Public Sub Calculate()

    MsgBox "Calculate"
    Call Calc_Mass

End Sub
```

"Calc_Mass" is also stored within Modules/Calculations. When I click the button I only see the first message box pop up with "Clicked".

Why is "Calculate" not being called?

Comment: Choose a different name than `Calculate`, which is equivalent to `Application.Calculate`.

Comment: Or specify the module name too: `Calculations.Calculate`

Comment: @ Rory Thanks also! I like that solution as I don't have to sacrifice my naming.